# How to get Google Chrome notifications in YouTube Gaming

Tags: youtube, notifications, google-chrome

I know how to receive Chrome notifications in https://youtube.com but I can't figure out how to do it in https://gaming.youtube.com .

I have looked at [this](https://support.google.com/youtubegaming/answer/6252165?hl=en) but still can't figure out how to do this.

Am I overlooking something, or is there no way to receive notifications from YouTube Gaming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desktop notifications are not available for YouTube Gaming at this time.

Comment: I'll just keep getting my notifications from normal youtube. Thanks.

Comment: Why was [this page](https://support.google.com/youtubegaming/answer/6252165?hl=en) put up?

Comment: That one is about the mobile apps.